fo-dicom c-store requst is ignored, but same file can be uploaded to pacs by dcmtk tool
I use fo-dicom to send a DCM file to PACS (PROPACS) via C-STORE. However, the PACS ignores my sending request and there is no response. I captured the packet by Wireshark, found that the DCM data packets have all been sent and the PACS has also sent acknowledgment, but then the PACS sends a FIN instruction following it. For the same DCM file, using dcmtk's storescu.exe can send successfully.
Here is the sample code:
 var client = DicomClientFactory.Create("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 104, false, "DemoScu", "PROPACS");
 var cSto = new DicomCStoreRequest(@"2.dcm");
 client.AddRequestAsync(cSto);
 cSto.OnResponseReceived += (req, response) =>
 Console.WriteLine("C-Store Response Received, Status: " + response.Status); 
 client.SendAsync();


You need to await the SendAsync method. The application is most likely closing before the Task is actually completed.

thanks, but I don't think await will be the solution. my application is still running there.

You have to await the async methods, otherwise there is no guaranty that your code will work:
var client = DicomClientFactory.Create("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 104, false, "DemoScu", "PROPACS");
var cSto = new DicomCStoreRequest(@"2.dcm");
**await** client.AddRequestAsync(cSto);
cSto.OnResponseReceived += (req, response) =>
    Console.WriteLine("C-Store Response Received, Status: " + response.Status); 
**await** client.SendAsync();

Otherwise, if you do not await, the the request might not have been properly added to the underlying serivce classes of the DicomClient. And also, when you only call SendAsync without awaiting this sending, then the DicomClient instance might get out of scope while the traffic is still in progress, and will be disposed by the Garbage Collector, and then when the final AssociationClose-workfow should happen, this might fail and the PACS does not consider the file as transfered completely.
